# Install packages in AWS sagemaker notebook jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, amazon-sagemaker-studio

I want to pip install the tensorflow-probability package in my AWS sagemaker notebook job. Everytime I run a notebook job, it tells me after the import statement that there is no module named tensorflow_probability.

I've tried to (1) %pip install it first and (2) used a notebook instance lifecycle script. None of them worked. Has anyone a idea? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Was the installation successful?

You can confirm if it was installed using:

```
!pip show tensorflow_probability
```

I had no issues installing in Studio Notebook Job and Notebook Instances:

```
%pip install tensorflow_probability
import tensorflow_probability
```